# error in android programming

Tags: java, android

There are two problems in this code, this is actually a simple code which aims to has a button and type a passage and when push the button and go to the next activity show the text had already written.

```
package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Main extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Reference from EditText
        final EditText matn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        // Reference from Button
        Button d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mafhoom = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
                mafhoom.putExtra("Selectedpassage", matn.getText().toString());
                startActivity(mafhoom);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: where is your second activity?

Comment: What is your errors ?

Comment: can you show your logcat?

Comment: `There are two problems in this code` ... **which** problems?

Comment: when I run this problem, show me errors in onclicklitenerssss!

Comment: @AminJaili What is that error?

Comment: could you show what error and error in this activity or second activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your code i just suggest you to

You should import

```
import android.content.View.OnClickListener;
```

instead of

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

OR `setOnClickListener(..)` like

```
 d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mafhoom = new Intent(Main.this, Second.class);
            mafhoom.putExtra("Selectedpassage", matn.getText().toString());
            startActivity(mafhoom);
        }

    });
```

Comment: but there is another error, when I  enter the passage to go to the next activity, to show what I typed before, there is an error.